# What is the maximum degree of rotation of R2-D2's primary limbs?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, r2-d2

R2-D2, from what I recall, can tilt his body forward or backward at approximately 45 degrees, most often backward as he rolls around using his third leg. Is it mechanically possible for him to tilt beyond that degree, anywhere close to what's demonstrated here (upside-down):

[image]

If no canon answer exists, legends answers are acceptable.

Comment: If it's not clear, I really am looking for any and all canon information on this topic. I know it's difficult to prove that no canon information exists, but before accepting a Legends answer, I will wait for a canon one.

Answer (score 2):

### Legends — A full 360 degrees

In the C-Canon *Star Wars: Droids: The Adventures of R2-D2 and C-3PO* episode "[Tail of the Roon Comets](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tail_of_the_Roon_Comets)", R2-D2 is shown to be capable of breakdancing, which involves completely rotating one of its limbs in a full 360 degree arc. Presumaby, it can do this with both limbs.

Comment: Oh, my goodness.

Comment: R2 was also *flexing* his legs and sliding his dome back and forth...

Comment: @pleurocoelus And yet believe it or not, this is considered C-Canon! Yeah, this scene was the ire of Legends canon fans for decades!

Comment: Why I love this site! Of course, I would prefer a Disney canon answer, but this is incredible.

Comment: @Thunderforge I believe it. Star Wars canon has had some crazy stuff in it...